# Can I play CoD MW3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, wine

I use Ubuntu 12.04. Before that I used Windows 8. Can I play "Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3" through wine?

The games that I could play before, can I play them now?

I only care about single-player mode so anything like "Steam" or "garena" or any other service like this, is useless for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good way to play Windows games on Ubuntu (and more generally Linux) is the [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) GUI for wine.

It uses custom scripts to make running and installing games smoother on wine. It has a really active community and there's good support.

Answer (score 2):

I have run older games like Call Of Duty 2 without any problems. In my experience wine is great a running things, but terrible at actually installing them which is problematic. I would recommend installing the game in windows xp then copying the windows xp installation (use xp to avoid directx issues) into a blank wine c: drive. At least that's what I used to do for games I wanted to run in wine. I've never tried your game in particular though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this page to find how games work on wine:

http://appdb.winehq.org/

The [latest entry](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13662) I can find on "Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3" is not positive, it seems to work quite badly. However, the entry is old, so it's possible that it works fine nowadays.

What games you can play depends solely on the game, so generally, you simply have to install and test for yourself.